# Suitable lapel/neckband microphone for dual mic presentation

Tags: audio-recording, audio, lapel, cardioid

So, I record a small youtube channel with a friend, we record games, camera is top down and we both have lapel mics as we tend to record in dining area's etc where it sounds a bit too echoey.

The problem is I'm louder than my friend and am often picked up on his lapel mic and when it comes to recording I try and add gate to his audio channel to remove as much as I can but my audio still sounds "echoey" because of his track picking me up.  Would a cardiod neckband mic help remove this unwanted bleeding, or should I just learn to shut up more?

Was thinking something like this perhaps?

https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B011DEGLPY/_encoding=UTF8?coliid=I3LHURCG0WOV2Q&colid=1CI6YSCLIZYCR&psc=1

Comment: tbh, at 20 quid I'd just get a pair & see. Considering a decent lav mic is going to be [3 - 400](https://www.thomann.de/gb/dpa_smk_4060_set.htm?sid=32bdf4eead41beecf9e98de471379548), they're not going to be stunning, but the directionality is going to help a bit, as well as the proximity.

Comment: £3/400 ?!  really?!

Comment: Yeah... the price has actually gone down over the years. I paid £450 for one of those 15 years ago... it's still in perfect working order & sounds simply wonderful.

Comment: my god thats insane!  I was a little peeved paying £15 for a pair off ebay 

Comment: You might want to sit down, then, before I tell you how much one of my good mics costs :) -  [Neuman U87](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/146361-REG/Neumann_U_87_AI_SET_Z_U87_Ai_SETZ_Nickel.html)

Comment:     I guess it all depends on how much you're getting out of it

Answer (score 1):

It depends how close you are to each other but yes the closer the microphone is to the source the lower the gain has to be to pick up the sound.

Comment: across the table from each other, so only a few feet 

Comment: That is a good position. The cardioid mic will reject noise coming from the back of it. Just make sure it's pointed in the right direction.